# How do I convert a 3D SBS dual-fisheye image to 3D SBS dual-equirectangular with only open-source tools?

Tags: ffmpeg, 3d, video-processing, virtual-reality, photography

Canon has released a new [3D VR lens for their RF mount](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/lenses/ef/vr/rf5-2mm-f2-8-l-dual-fisheye-lens) and I recently rented it to see what it's like to work with. Unfortunately, they charge a subscription fee for their conversion software, which I've also found to be inconveniently limited in real-world use cases. Thus I'm interested in an open-source approach to converting the video captured by this lens using something like `ffmpeg`.

The video is dual-fisheye and the Canon tool produces dual-equirectangular side-by-side video. I would like to perform this same conversion in `ffmpeg` or a similarly-powerful open-source tool.

Related questions exist but aren't quite correct. Most dual-fisheye input seems to be used to create 360-degree 2D video, not 3D SBS.

Comment: Not familiar with 3D SBS or lens geometry, but it looks like you can put together a filtergraph to do what you want with 2 parallel `crop` filters to split left and right, and each cropped streams individually go through lens correction filters like `lensfun`, `lenscorrection`, then merge them back together with `hstack`. Glanced at [this article](https://www.danielplayfaircal.com/blogging/ffmpeg/lensfun/v360/lenscorrection/fisheye/dodgeball/2020/03/24/correcting-lens-distortion-with-ffmpeg.html) for lens correction filters, which may be useful for you (if you haven't seen it already)

Comment: when converting dual-fisheye ffmpeg does not care if it is 360 degree video or 3d SBS (no stitching is performed). So, maybe 'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf v360=input=dfisheye:iv_fov=185:ih_fov=185:output=equirect output.mp4' does the trick? You could add a link to an example video, if it is still relevant I could give it a try.